# Will using DirectX or OpenGL speed up 2D Rendering on a windows form?

Tags: c#, opengl, directx

I'm working on a structured light project where I need to project what are essentially barcodes at 60fps.  These codes are built from bitmap images that are 1920x1200.  When using GDI in C# I'm only getting around 19fps on a pretty beastly computer.  I'm looking into SharpDX now and before investing a lot of time I was wondering if rendering the images to the screen via DirectX or OpenGL will actually be faster?

Sample code:

```
// Gets a reference to the current BufferedGraphicsContext
currentContext = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current;
List<Image> imagesGrayCode = new List<Image>();

Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile("F:/LAB/Hardware Triggering Demo/Lib/Patterns_11bit_RLL.tiff");
int count = bitmap.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);

for (int idx = 0; idx < count; idx++)
{
    // save each frame to a bytestream
    bitmap.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, idx);
    MemoryStream byteStream = new MemoryStream();
    bitmap.Save(byteStream, ImageFormat.Tiff);

    // and then create a new Image from it
    imagesGrayCode.Add(Image.FromStream(byteStream));
    //this.progressBar1.Value = idx;
}


Thread.Sleep(1000);
stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
int acq_wait_time = 10;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    foreach (Image img in imagesGrayCode)
    {
        myBuffer.Graphics.DrawImage(img, this.DisplayRectangle);
        // Renders the contents of the buffer to the drawing surface associated with the buffer.
        myBuffer.Render();
        // Renders the contents of the buffer to the specified drawing surface.
        myBuffer.Render(this.CreateGraphics());

        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(acq_wait_time);
        stopwatch.Reset();
        stopwatch.Start();
        while (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < acq_wait_time)
        { }
        FPS++;
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
```

Updated Code:

```
// Gets a reference to the current BufferedGraphicsContext
currentContext = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current;
List<Image> imagesGrayCode = new List<Image>();
List<BufferedGraphics> ImageBuffers = new List<BufferedGraphics>();
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile("F:/LAB/Hardware Triggering Demo/Lib/Patterns_11bit_RLL.tiff");
int count = bitmap.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);

for (int idx = 0; idx < count; idx++)
{
    // save each frame to a bytestream
    bitmap.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, idx);
    MemoryStream byteStream = new MemoryStream();
    bitmap.Save(byteStream, ImageFormat.Tiff);

    // and then create a new Image from it
    imagesGrayCode.Add(Image.FromStream(byteStream));
    //this.progressBar1.Value = idx;
}

//create a buffer from each image in memory
for (int i = 0; i < imagesGrayCode.Count(); i++)
{
    ImageBuffers.Add(currentContext.Allocate(this.CreateGraphics(),this.DisplayRectangle));
    ImageBuffers.ElementAt(i).Graphics.DrawImage(imagesGrayCode.ElementAt(i), this.DisplayRectangle);
    ImageBuffers.ElementAt(i).Render();
}

Thread.Sleep(1000);
stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
int acq_wait_time = 10;

for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    //display image buffers sequentially
    for (int i = 0; i < imagesGrayCode.Count(); i++)
    {
        // Renders the contents of the buffer to the specified drawing surface.
        ImageBuffers.ElementAt(i).Render(this.CreateGraphics());

        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(acq_wait_time);
        stopwatch.Reset();
        stopwatch.Start();
        while (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < acq_wait_time)
        { }
        FPS++;
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337466/should-we-use-opengl-for-2d-graphics) topic covers all three with a good explination from somebody that understands the backend. However after a few google searches the general consensus is using a rendering api like opengl or directx better leverages modern gpus and you can expect a performance boost, even in 2D works. GDI+ is a thing too.

Comment: You want to avoid `Application.DoEvents();` as it can lead to your application becoming **re-entrant**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're drawing > rendering > drawing > rendering > drawing > rendering etc. You can do all the drawing ahead of time so you only need to render on each frame. Use more of whatever myBuffer is; one for each image.

Profiler tools are awesome for these problems. I'm guessing based on your partial code and my experience, but a profiler can tell you *exactly* how long each function takes to complete.

Comment: I took David's advice and saw my FPS increase to the 90's.  Updated code posted to question area.